# Are django models thread safe?

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I used to populate a database using a django based front end and then use the data in my daemon software accessing the mysql db directly.

Now I want to integrate the django models into the daemon software directly to make developement more easy.

So wrote this class:

```
class DjangoMysqlConnector:
  def __init__(self,SystemLogger=False):
    path_list = ["/home/user/django/bildverteiler_project/", "/home/user/git/apps/"]

    for path in path_list:
      if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bildverteiler_project.settings")
    django.setup()

    from bildverteiler import models
    self.models = models

  def get_all_servers(self):
    return models.Server.objects.all()
  def get_all_verteilers(self):
    return models.Verteiler.objects.all()
```

Now I'm wondering: Is this thread safe?

Can I create one object from that class and pass it to multiple threads?

Will this stay true when I add functions that write to the db as well?

Comment: I can't honestly see what the point of this class is. It doesn't seem to be doing anything useful, and is not storing any state. Why not access `models.Server` etc in your code?

Comment: I don't want to the django code all over my application. Also since I did this using mysql directly I just want to replace the existing mysql-db-class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to elaborate a bit about what you mean with thread safe. If you're not planning on using a lock, then of course it's not thread safe.  For instance,

```
s = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)
s.field = 2
s.save()
```

will obviously not be consistent if 3 threads are doing it at the same time. However, `SomeModel.objects.filter(pk=1).update(field=2)` is actually threadsafe. Use `transaction.atomic()` to maintain thread safety. Although, there could be a problem spawning alot of threads and connecting to the database at the same time, make sure you're allowed to open as many connections as planned.

An efficient way to do this would be to have one thread that's doing all the database interactions, while the other threads are doing calculations or whatever your plan is. Pass the objects on a `Queue` to synchronize.

Comment: If I put it in another thread. How can I pass the received db data back to the calling thread? I think inserting is easy the way you propose, but how can I access retrieved data? Also when I Insert I sometimes need the resulting primary key back in the calling thread.

Comment: If you were to present an example, I would more likely be able to help you.

Comment: I don't understand how adding `transaction.atomic( )` makes it threadsafe ? Can you elaborate. Thanks